# Is there anyway to upload a file without using temp directory?

Tags: php, file-upload

I created file transfer website using HTML5 chunking file api using http. It works fine, except that during uploading the file, the CPU usage in server is almost 100%. This file transfer will be used to upload file on average around 4GB.

My guess is that it takes cpu usage almost 100% because it try to move the file from tmp directory to destination directory.

Is there anyway to upload a file without using temp directory?

My question is for PHP but other language will be accepted

Here is the result of "top" command during uploading files (18mb, 38mb, 60mb, 33mb)

```
 1904 apache    20   0 33504 5740 1952 R 28.3  0.2   0:02.19 httpd
 1905 apache    20   0 33504 5740 1952 R 28.3  0.2   0:01.99 httpd
 1903 apache    20   0 33232 6968 3060 R 28.0  0.2   0:01.98 httpd
 1910 apache    20   0 33240 6020 2248 S 11.5  0.2   0:02.85 httpd
 2133 root      20   0  2656 1124  896 R  1.6  0.0   0:00.71 top
    1 root      20   0  2864 1404 1188 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.99 init
```

it shows that httpd take all the resources..
Is there anyone know what's the problem if it's not because of copying or uploading the files to the server?

Comment: I highly doubt that the CPU image would go over a couple percent when copying a file. Why don't you do some more research and pinpoint the cause exactly?

Comment: Listen to teh teh1.... :-D Seriously though he is right. It's highly unlikely that copying process is what makes your CPU spike...

Comment: @teh1 any idea what could cause the CPU to spike, check my "top" command result on linux server. it shows that httpd taking up all the cpu resource 28.3, 28.3, ...

Comment: @Harts, you are suffering from a misguided [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135887).  With no evidence, you believe that moving temp files -- *simple I/O* -- is causing high load, therefore you want to skip using temp files.  You have no evidence that temp files are the problem, and I will eat a dozen top hats if it is.  Your real problem is insane CPU time used by Apache.  Troubleshoot *that*.

Comment: I'd guess you've got an infinite loop or something.

Comment: Please post 'uname -a' result.

IO handling on certain linux kernel can cause high CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the http put method to handle the file upload. In this method the data is directly streamed to the PHP script and you can handle it using file functions:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('php://input','r');
while(!feof($f)){
    $chunk = fread($f,CHUNK_SIZE);
    [Handle the uploading file here]
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

(Replace CHUNK_SIZE with your value)

Comment: is there any security concern difference between PUT and POST? Is it possible to Upload multiple file with PUT method?

Comment: You can upload multiple files using put but you need to issue a request for every files you're going to upload. That means you can't upload multiple files in one request.

Comment: I think by the time you can access php://input, the file is already uploaded and stored in tmp file.

Comment: See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure moving from tmp to destination is the problem, you can change php.ini settings  (upload_tmp_dir) to move tmp dir to another directory in the same paatition with the destination directory.

Don't just change it in your script, by the time your script ran, the file is already uploaded.

Just change it in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should profile your application a little bit more, cause moving files will not occupy CPU dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

For files so large as 4GB, you might consider setting up a websocket to stream to for your application.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploade-in-node-js/

Comment: using websocket, does that means I need to specify the ip and it's open up a socket? will it work if multiple people trying to upload at the same time? or each person I need to specify each own socket?